# Is my layout window open?

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to execute some code only *if a given layout window is **open*** ...
Is there a way to programmatically detect this ? I've browsed the **QgsPrintLayout** and **QgsLayout** classes and i didn't find anything helpful ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is simple,you only need this:

```
iface.openLayoutDesigners()
```

if this return a empty list, all layout is closed.

Comment: lol sorry ... didn't think i was that easy ... i feel so lame not to be able to find it in the help ...

Comment: sorry to ask that one more question but ... : when i browse the content of this **openLayoutDesigners()** i get a list of **openLayoutDesignerInterface** then using for example **iface.openLayoutDesigners()[0].layout()** i get a **QgsLayout** object ... How can i retrieve the layout's **name** which seems to be an attribute of the **QgsPrintLayout class** ? Thanks !

Comment: The answer is : **iface.openLayoutDesigners()[0].masterLayout().name()**

Comment: That will fail if the list is empty!Need check list a loop values

Comment: yep i bear that in mind ... thx